# How to grep out the variables in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I would like to know how can I grep out (exclude) variables inside a file?

For example file.txt:

```
PATH1=/path/to/file
PATH2=/path/to/anotherfile
PATH3=/path/to/thirdfile
TEST=$(echo $RANDOM)

* * * * *\5 top -n 1 > /tmp/$TEST
* * * * * echo hello # = for deletion
```

I want to print only the cron job without variables:
e.g:

```
* * * * *\5 top -n 1 > /tmp/$TEST
* * * * * echo hello # = for deletion
```

note that there are equal signs at the end, i need to keep these lines as well.
tailing this file is not a solution, there can be more than just 1 line that is not a variable of course.
any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Vixie cron, a crontab line is:

1. a comment if the first non-blank character is #
2. an environment setting if the first non-blank character is a letter or _
3. a cron command if the first non-blank character is a digit, * or @
4. a blank line if there is no non-blank character
5. otherwise, an error.

So to grep for case 3 (cron command):

```
grep -E '^[[:blank:]]*[0-9*@]'
```

Alternatively, to remove case 2 (environment setting) but leave everything else, including comments and errors:

```
grep -Ev '^[[:blank:]]*[a-zA-Z_]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -v`

```
 grep -v '=' filename
```

Or you can `grep` only for the required entry.

```
$ grep '\*' filename
* * * * *\5 top -n 1 > /tmp/$TEST
```

Comment: @dolevf You can `grep` for the cron entry. You'll have to provide a specific pattern which differentiates the required line from others.

Comment: The second match will also not work if all 5 numeric cron parameters are set.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following grep which will exclude only variable setting lines:

```
grep -iv '^[[:blank:]]*[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*[[:blank:]]*='
```

Comment: Not quite; there can be whitespace before and/or after the variable name. But it's closer.

Comment: true, white spaces before and/or after are still displayed

Comment: No, the real problem is that a variable assignment can have whitespace in front, and then your regex misses the line.

Comment: crontab man pages states variables can be declared with whitespaces before and after equal sign, this may be highly unusual, but it may happen :)

Comment: I agree that it is a possibility.  I've just never seen it.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer!
You question made me think why do you want to filter declaration out...because declarations does not "*do actual work*" . In this sense they are invisible :)

So my solution filters out invisible commands like declaration...of course if this example.txt contains `rm -Rf /` that would be funny or other unix commands still makes no output so you can combine it with some kind of `=` char search.

So my point is that declaration makes no output, other words would do...here is my funny answer:

```
$ export IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(cat /tmp/example.txt);do if [ "$(eval $line 2>&1 )" != "" ];then echo "RESULT PRINTING: $line";else echo "DEF NOT PRINTING: $line";fi; done
DEF NOT PRINTING: PATH1=/path/to/file
DEF NOT PRINTING: PATH2=/path/to/anotherfile
DEF NOT PRINTING: PATH3=/path/to/thirdfile
DEF NOT PRINTING: TEST=$(echo $RANDOM)
RESULT PRINTING: * * * * *\5 top -n 1 > /tmp/$TEST
RESULT PRINTING: * * * * * echo hello # = for deletion
```

Comment: Thanks a alot, but  this solutions seems a little unclean for my specific need